# XML-file produce by the SqlPivotScriptProducer does not contain additonal indexes

Tags: codefluent

We are using the following producers :

- sqlServer producer
- Template Producer
- SqlPivotScriptProducer

With the template producer we create additional indexes.
The xml-file produced by the SqlPivotScriptProducer does not contain these additonal indexes.

Has anybody an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The Pivot Script Producer generates the pivot file with the information from the model and the SQL Server database. In short, it uses the model to get a list of the objects that should be in the pivot file and uses the database to get the real definition of each object. For instance if your template replaces a stored procedure defined in the model, the pivot script will contain the definition of the stored procedure as in the template.So if your template creates new database objects (not in the model), they won't be in the pivot file.

You can customize the `PivotRunner` using the `Action` event

```
PivotRunner pivotRunner = new PivotRunner("Pivot\\Model1.pivot.xml");
pivotRunner.ConnectionString = CodeFluentContext.Get(Constants.Model1StoreName).Configuration.ConnectionString;
pivotRunner.Action += OnAction;
pivotRunner.Run();
```